# What is the particle's average velocity when it crosses half the maximum height?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

A particle is thrown with velocity $u$ at an angle $\theta$ from the $ UPWARD 
\space VERTICAL$

Here i have tried to put $\dfrac{H}{2}=\dfrac{{u^2}{{\cos^2 \theta}}}{4g}$ in the equation of trajectory
$$\dfrac{{u^2}{{\cos^2 \theta}}}{4g}=x\cot \theta \Big(1-\dfrac{x}{R}\Big)$$
$$\dfrac{{u^2}{{\sin \theta \cos \theta}}}{4g}=x\Big(1-\dfrac{x}{R}\Big)$$
$$\dfrac{R}{8}=x\Big(1-\dfrac{x}{R}\Big)$$
Solving this equation gives me $$x=\dfrac{8R\pm 4R\sqrt{2}}{16}$$
Please tell me if i am wrong or is there any other method to do this question.

(I was trying to find $y$ and $x$ so that i may find displacement over this interval)

Comment: Average velocity between what two points?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your expression for the half height is correct.  Put it into an equation for conservation of energy and solve for the instantaneous velocity at that point.

Comment: Please do not provide answers to questions that are off-topic